# When user inputs text passing through props from another component not working in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, components

I am trying to concat the data entered in text field passing data from another stateless component, using props. Not sure why it is not working.

I have created two components

1. app.js 2. title.js 
   Data entered in input field needs to concat the string every time and display dynamically using props.

   App.js

   ```
   import React, { Component } from 'react';
   import logo from './logo.svg';
   import './App.css';
   import Home from './Home';
   import Title from './Title';

   class App extends Component {

     constructor(props)
     {
       super(props);
       this.state =
       {
         text : ' ',
         collection: []
       }
       this.eventHandler = this.eventHandler.bind(this);
       this.eventSubmit = this.eventSubmit.bind(this);

     }

     eventHandler(event)
   {

     this.setState(
       {text:event.target.value}
       )
   }

   eventSubmit(event)
   {
     this.setState(
       {collection:this.state.collection.concat(this.state.text)}
       )

   }

     render() {
      return (
         <div className="App">
         <input type="text" onChange ={this.eventHandler}  />
         <p> {this.state.text} </p>
         <input type="submit" onClick={this.eventSubmit} />  
         <title collection={this.state.collection} />
         </div>
       );
     }
   }
   export default App;
   ```

   Title.js

   ```
   import React from 'react';

   const title = (props) =>
   {

   return (
       <div>
       <h1> {this.props.collection.toString()} </h1>
       <h1> hello </h1>
       </div>
   );
   }
   export default title;
   ```

Answer (score 1):

setState is async and when you use this.state inside it, it might not re-render. Use function inside setState instead:

```
eventSubmit(event) {
    this.setState((prevState, props) => ({
        collection: prevState.collection.concat(prevState.text)
    }));
}
```

See 3. setState() is async: https://codeburst.io/how-to-not-react-common-anti-patterns-and-gotchas-in-react-40141fe0dcd

Answer (score 0):

Mutations are bad in general and can lead to side effects use spread operator(...) to copy prevState array instead.

```
eventSubmit(event) {
    this.setState((prevState) => ({
        collection: [...prevState.collection, prevState.text]
    }));
}
```

That's how you append data in array and update the state

Answer (score 0):

```
Instead of stateless component I have created class component and it worked. Can someone explain me why it didn't worked with stateless why it worked now.

App.js

<code>
        import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import Home from './Home';
import Title from './Title';
import Collection from './Collection';

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props)
  {
    super(props);
    this.state =
    {
      text : ' ',
      collection: []
    }
    this.eventHandler = this.eventHandler.bind(this);
    this.eventSubmit = this.eventSubmit.bind(this);  
  }

eventHandler(event)
{
this.setState(
{text:event.target.value}
    )
}
eventSubmit(event)
{
  this.setState(
    {collection:this.state.collection.concat(this.state.text)}
   )

}
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">

      <h1> ramesh </h1>
      <input type="text" onChange ={this.eventHandler}  />
      <p> {this.state.text} </p>
      <input type="submit" onClick={this.eventSubmit} />  
      <title name ={this.state.collection} />
      <Collection name={this.state.collection} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default App;

</code>

Collection.js

<code>
import React, {Component} from 'react';

class Collection extends React.Component
{
    render()
    {
        return( 

            <div>
            <h1> {this.props.name.toString()} </h1>
            </div>

         );
    }
}
export default Collection;
</code>
```